# Git rebase fails because: Commit xxxx is a merge but no -m option was given

Tags: git, github, rebase, cherry-pick

I had a feature branch:

```
feature
```

with lets say 10 commits

then some time ago I started doing experiments on it, but wanted to preserve the current functionality just in case, so I started a new branch:

```
feature-experiment
```

and then did another 10 commits

today I decided to `merge` `feature-experiment` into `feature` and then I deleted `feature-experiment`. There were some merge conflicts which I resolved.

then, my 20 commits which were all using the same name and ending in `WIP` (work in progress), were very ugly, so I decided to

```
git rebase -p -i HEAD~22
```

I changed `pick` to `s` to squash them all into the oldest commit for this feature, but I had some merge conflicts (the same as before). I resolved them and then

```
git add -A && git commit

git rebase --continue
```

but now I get the following error:

```
error: Commit asd123qsd is a merge but no -m     option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
Could not pick asd123qsd
```

This is the last commit (the merge one)

I tried again, but this time I didnt change this particular commit's `pick` to `s`, but got the same error.

How can I carry out this dreadful rebase?

I was thinking, as a possible solution, I could I modify the last commit to add -m to it, but how do I do that and what do I do with this -m command? Are there any other options

Comment: This is strange, because normally merge commits should be excluded by a rebase unless you explicitly pass the `--preserve-merges` flag...

Comment: I did pass it, actually (`-p`)

Comment: should I try without it?

Comment: I tried without it but now a conflict comes up from much before the `feature` branch was creatd and I don't know how to resolve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely here:

`git rebase -p -i HEAD~22`

The `-p` option is described in [the git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) as the short version of `--preserve-merges`:

> **-p**
>
> **--preserve-merges**
>
> Recreate merge commits instead of flattening the history by replaying
>   commits a merge commit introduces. Merge conflict resolutions or
>   manual amendments to merge commits are not preserved.
>
> This uses the --interactive machinery internally, but combining it
>   with the --interactive option explicitly is generally not a good idea
>   unless you know what you are doing (see BUGS below).

Since you're trying to squash commits here, preserving merge commits is almost certainly not what you want. Additionally, the warning about combining the `--preserve-merges` flag with the `--interactive` (`-i`) flag is likely relevant here.

Honestly though, **using a rebase to do a squash like this may be introducing a lot more complexity than what you need here**. If all you want is to squash all of the changes from this branch into a single commit, you can do that like this:

```
git checkout feature
git reset --soft <base of feature branch>
```

At this point all the changes from your feature branch should be staged, and the feature branch should be at the base commit. Now you can simply run `git commit` to create a new commit containing all the changes from your feature branch, which is basically equivalent to a squash.

Comment: Thank you I will try that! What should I put in the placeholder you used `<base of feature branch>`? the commit that I want to start with?

Comment: That would be the commit your branch is based off of. For example, if you branched off of master, then `git merge-base master feature` should print the hash of the commit to use for that step. (It should be the parent of the first commit on the feature branch.)

Comment: I did this and then pushed. Was rejected, because the other branch had advanced, so I pulled, then pushed. Went to GitHub but all 20 commits are still there and this new one is there as well. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @J.K. That's a general problem with _all_ git operations that rewrite history. (Rebase, squash, --amend, etc.) The other branch likely didn't "advance", it just still contained the unsquashed commits that were no longer in your local branch. So when you ran `git pull` it merged all those commits back into your local branch. (Because that's what `pull` is for.) You have to push with `--force` whenever you want to delete commits (i.e. rewrite history) on a remote branch. Assuming that *is* what you intended, `reset --hard` back to the squashed commit and push again with `--force`.

Comment: by the `squashed commit` you mean `<base of feature branch>` or the one that I just uploaded? after that commit, there is some merge commit added as well, so which of those 3 should I reset hard to? I am really sorry for asking so many questions

Comment: I would have tried all 3 variants but I dont want to mess up even more @Ajedi32

Comment: @J.K. I mean the squashed commit you just committed.